# Remapping characters in xmodmap

Tags: linux, keyboard, xmodmap

I am using a Swedish keyboard, and I want to be able to type braces easier.

I planned to map `AltGr + å` to '}' and `AltGr + ä` to '{'. However, nothing really changes. I have some other stuff in my.Xmodmap so I know that it gets loaded allright. Here's what I have so far:

```
keycode 35 = slash asciitilde dead_ogonek section dead_ogonek section
keycode 49 = asciicircum onehalf
keycode 66 = F10
clear Lock
keycode 34 = aring Aring braceleft
keycode 48 = adiaeresis Adiaeresis braceright
```

Where the 2 last lines are the one that should be related to this. What could I be doing wrong?

Is there some other way I can solve it in Linux?

**Update:**

```
keycode 34 = aring Aring aring Aring braceleft dead_abovering
keycode 48 = adiaeresis Adiaeresis adiaeresis Adiaeresis braceright ae
```

Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
xmodmap -pke
```

and checked that these lines still appear in that form in the output? There could be other startup scripts that override some of your settings...

Comment: I ran xmodmap -pke (without having loaded my .Xmodmap rewrites), copy/pasted the output to .Xmodmap replacing the exact characters I wanted to replace with braces, and it now works!